# Foundation Axiom/Set Theorem Exercise

Tags: set-theory, foundations

(Hopefully, I'm asking question in the right place this time!)

[exercise 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4gTq.png)

I am trying to do the above exercise question (I don't have enough reputation to post inline picture, please click on "exercise 2") on Set Theory Axioms. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I thought $T ∈ U ∈ V ∈ T$ leads to $T ∈ T$, but the answer says $T ∉ T$. Please enlighten me!

([Question source: MIT OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/proofs/tp4-3/set-theory-axioms-optional-0/))

Comment: You should make the question self-contained, if necessary by re-typing the problem itself either verbatim or in your own words. Personally regardless of whether you can include an image I recommend always re-typing the problem in your own words: it's a helpful thing to do on its own.

Answer (score 2):

The problem states that $T\in U\in V\in T$ and **there are no other membership relations among them**. $T\in T$ would be a membership relation among them in addition to $T\in U$, $U\in V$, and $V\in T$, and by hypothesis no such relation exists. For the same reason we know that $T\notin V$ and $V\notin V$ in the fourth part.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $a\in b\in c$ does **not** mean $a\in c$: consider e.g. $a=\emptyset, b=\{\emptyset\}, c=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. (This is a key difference between "$\in$" and "$\subseteq,$" the latter of which **is** transitive.)

However, Foundation is strong enough to rule this "deeper self-elementhood" as well. The idea behind applying Foundation to rule out some configuration is to think of "$\in$" as meaning "smaller than," and whip up some set which is "circular." E.g. intuitively we have the following circle here: $$...\in U\in V\in T\in U\in V\in T\in  ...$$ Note that already "$U\in V\in T\in U$" describes the whole circle. So our idea for a set with no "$\in$-least element" should just be

> This circle itself: namely, $X=\{U, V, T,U\}$, or less redundantly just $X=\{U,V,T\}$.

And this would indeed be a counterexample to Foundation:

> The set $X$ has three elements, namely $U,V,T$. And each of these has nonempty intersection with $X$: $T\in U\cap X$, $U\in V\cap X$, and $V\in T\cap X$.